# How to handle and report to client Web Service Exceptions?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, exception, client-applications

I have two applications. A spring-boot web service and another that consumes it. I'm not sure how to handle exceptions and report them back to the client.

The method that exposes the web-service:

```
//web service com springboot
    @PostMapping(value = "/save", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
                    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Pessoa save(@RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {    
        // email field is unique, might throw constraint violation...   
            return pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);               
    }
```

and the client application that consumes it (without spring, just javaEE Client API):

```
public Pessoa savePessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target(URL_WS+ "/save");

    Entity<Pessoa> data = Entity.entity(pessoa, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

    pessoa = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).post(data, Pessoa.class);

    return pessoa;
}
```

The email field of Pessoa is unique, and when saving can trigger some constraint violation exception.
If there is an exception how can I properly report this to client?

Answer (score 0):

Create a exception class

```
public class PessoaException extends RuntimeException { 
   public PessoaException(String exception) {
    super(exception);
      }
    }
```

change your service code as below :-

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/save", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
                    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Pessoa save(@RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {    
        // email field is unique, might throw constraint violation... 
            try{
            Pessoa p = pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new PessoaException("Message" + e);
            }   
            return p;               
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! And how would the client check if the object sent was persisted successfully?